# grep with sort on column

Tags: grep

I have the following test.txt. Using below command its printing output: xvf-9c3683ff. However I need the output xvf-bcb500df. It is based on its last date.

cat test.txt | sort -k2 | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' | grep xvf | head -1

test.txt

```
{
    "date": "2017-01-30T10:55:46.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-9c3683ff"
}, 
{
    "date": "2017-01-26T12:58:20.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-bcb500df"
}, 
{
    "date": "2017-01-31T18:33:20.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-ee07b28d"
}
```

output should print below result.
xvf-bcb500df

Comment: is that JSON output?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a JSON formatted file (it lacks `[` in the beginning and `]` at the end), with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq 'sort_by(.date)' data.json
[
  {
    "date": "2017-01-26T12:58:20.000Z",
    "Id": "xvf-bcb500df"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-30T10:55:46.000Z",
    "Id": "xvf-9c3683ff"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-31T18:33:20.000Z",
    "Id": "xvf-ee07b28d"
  }
]
```

To get the first `Id`:

```
$ jq 'sort_by(.date)|.[0].Id' data.json
"xvf-bcb500df"
```

To get it without the quotes:

```
$ jq -r 'sort_by(.date)|.[0].Id' data.json
xvf-bcb500df
```

Data in a structured and standard format should be parsed with a parser written for the task. There are readily available parsers for use in shell script or on the command line for several common formats, including [JSON](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), [XML](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), [CSV](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) and others.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: reajusting format:

```
$ cat data.json | json -ga date Id
2017-01-30T10:55:46.000Z xvf-9c3683ff
2017-01-26T12:58:20.000Z xvf-bcb500df
2017-01-31T18:33:20.000Z xvf-ee07b28d
```

Next step: sort and print just ID:

```
cat data.json | json -ga date Id | sort | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
```

json comand line tool is documented in http://trentm.com/json/ . If necessary,

- install node
- and sudo npm install -g json

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
| awk '{print $2}' | sed -n '/"/N;s/\n//;s/"//gp' | sort | awk -F, '/xvf/{print $2}' | head -n1
```

Example:

```
$ echo '{
    "date": "2017-01-30T10:55:46.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-9c3683ff"
}, 
{
    "date": "2017-01-26T12:58:20.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-bcb500df"
}, 
{
    "date": "2017-01-31T18:33:20.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-ee07b28d"
}' | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n '/"/N;s/\n//;s/"//gp' | sort | awk -F, '/xvf/{print $2}' | head -n1
xvf-bcb500df
```

***EDIT - Python approach***

Make sure your data is valid `JSON`, then you can use the following script:

```
import json

with open('test.txt', 'rt') as file:
   data = sorted(json.load(file), key=lambda x: x['date'])
   print(data[0]['Id'])
```

Comment: This works !! Just modify the command to remove the double quote.  | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n '/"/N;s/\n//p' | sort | awk -F, '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' | head -n1

Comment: @user213618 Please see edited answer.

Comment: edited command works !! but it does not work with the following  case.                                         
{
    "date": "2017-01-30T10:55:46.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-9c3683ff",
    "mr": "available"
}, 
{
    "date": "2017-01-26T12:58:20.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-bcb500df"
    "mr": "active"
}, 
{
    "date": "2017-01-31T18:33:20.000Z", 
    "Id": "xvf-ee07b28d"
    "mr": "pending"
}

Comment: You must use properly formatted JSON, otherwise it will not work, thus it must be: `echo -e '{\n"date": "2017-01-30T10:55:46.000Z",\n"Id": "xvf-9c3683ff", "mr": "available"\n},\n{\n"date": "2017-01-26T12:58:20.000Z",\n"Id": "xvf-bcb500df" "mr": "active"\n},\n{\n"date": "2017-01-31T18:33:20.000Z",\n"Id": "xvf-ee07b28d" "mr": "pending"\n}' | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n '/"/N;s/\n//;s/"//gp' | sort | awk -F, '/xvf/{print $2}' | head -n1`. If your real intent is JSON parsing - you should really look to other answers, I only showed you how to do it using standard tools set.

Comment: @user213618 See edited question, to learn how to use Python to parse json. You just need to make sure, your original sample is enclosed in square brackets `[`, `]`.